# How to connect to a RDS in private subnet using MySQL Workbench?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I just created the following architecture in a VPC for a project :

- 1 public subnet with a bastion (EC2 instance) in it
- 1 private subnet with an EC2 instance and a RDS instance in it
  I use the bastion to connect to the EC2 private instance (with ssh agent forwarding using Putty and Pageant) and my RDS instance is connected to the private EC2 instance.

My question is : How do I do to connect to my RDS instance using MySQL Workbench on my local PC wiht this architecture ?

I have read that it is simple if I just connect my RDS instance directly to the bastion but it seems awful in term of architecture.

Comment: You don't so much "connect my RDS instance directly to the bastion". Rather, the database is _accessed_ via the bastion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it seems awful in term of architecture.

This is how it is done. You need to have a bastion host in a **private subnet** and setup an **ssh tunnel** to the RDS instance. This can be dune using **session manager** as explained in AWS docs:

- [Securely connect to an Amazon RDS or Amazon EC2 database instance remotely with your preferred GUI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/securely-connect-to-an-amazon-rds-or-amazon-ec2-database-instance-remotely-with-your-preferred-gui/)

You can also setup regular ssh tunnel, without session manager, but this requires bastion in a **public subent**:

- [Connecting to an AWS MySQL RDS using a Bastion Host](https://dev.to/aws-builders/connecting-to-an-aws-mysql-rds-using-a-bastion-host-265j)

Comment: To clarify... The connection will be made from the Bastion to the Amazon RDS database. The 'private' EC2 instance will not be involved in the connection.

Comment: So you're telling me that the better way is to connect to the RDS directly through the bastion host instead of connecting to it through the private EC2 which this one is accessible via the bastion host ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There is no benefit to going via the private EC2 instance unless you wish to lock-down the Security Group to _only_ allow access via the private EC2 instance. You would need to "double-jump", which is more difficult to setup.

Comment: @Marcin as is pointed out in the article you linked to, one of the advantages of using the SSM solution is that *"With Session Manager, you can maintain the security blanket of a bastion host, but in a private subnet and without opening any ports, and connect to Amazon RDS direct from your workstation."* So the statement that *"You need to have a bastion host in a public subnet and setup an ssh tunnel to the RDS instance"* isn't correct when using the SSH over SSM solution, because the bastion can be in a private subnet in that case.